# Log off after pressing 5 times Windows logo key - How to disable?

Tags: windows-10-v1607

I have a basic installation of Windows 10 2016 LTSB (1607) on an industrial PC ( I am the developer)

If i press the Windows logo key 5 times, i get logged off.

This happens with different keyboards and a VM as well. Sticky keys are switched off.

There are no related keyboard options in BIOS.

I do not find any related configuration, GPO ect..

How do i disable this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to Prabu_Mbt on the [Microsoft forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/097cd21e-0c84-43e7-8af8-9475982112e2/when-windows-key-is-pressed-for-multiple-times-the-system-is-getting-locked-in-win10-iot-enterprise?forum=win10itprogeneral), this should be your answer:

The reg key **"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Embedded\Keyboardfilter"**
**BreakoutKeyScanCode** is creating this issue. You can remove this key or set it to 0.

> Explanation: This setting specifies the scan code of the key that
>   enables a user to break out of an account that is locked down with
>   Keyboard Filter. A user can press this key consecutively five times
>   quickly to switch to the Welcome screen. Set to the scan code for the
>   left Windows logo key by default.
>
> Reference:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449330(v=winembedded.82).aspx

Comment: Wow, that was fast !
Problem solved. Thank you.